# Android crash due to layout casting

Tags: android-layout, casting

Android Studio 1.1.0, java 8, Windows 7 pro 64bit

My App crashes with a run-time fatal exception, the following error in the log.
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams

it does not crash if I comment out the second line in the java file. But how can I fix this problem, I do not see such a casting taking place in my code.

Thank you

```
    RelativeLayout headerSection = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.contact_view_header); //fetch the layout
    headerSection.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, (int) (width * (9.0 / 16.0))));
```

Here is the xml file

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="au.com.totalcareauto.sam.mycontacts.ContactViewActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/contact_view_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/contact_view_image"
        android:src="@mipmap/sunset"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contact_view_name"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/vertical_margin_small"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/contact_view_toolbar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/contact_view_fields"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="100"
    android:layout_height="0dp" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making wrong choice for the subclass of LayoutParams.

The correct form of LayoutParams should depend upon the **LinearLayout** not on **RelativeLayout** as the **LinearLayout** is the **parent view** in your case and **RelativeLayout** is **child view**.

So you can use **LinearLayout.LayoutParams** instead of **RelativeLayout.LayoutParams** or you can use RelativeLayout as your Root view.

```
 RelativeLayout headerSection = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.contact_view_header); //fetch the layout
 headerSection.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, (int) (width * (9.0 / 16.0))));
```

I think this will solve your problem. I have tested it out and it's working fine.